# Identify 8-pin surface mount component on motherboard

Tags: identification, surface-mount, motherboard

I'm trying to identify a surface mount component on an Asus ROG Maximus X Hero motherboard that I'm trying to repair for a friend. The board does not boot up after a power supply failed. I have found using a thermal camera that when power is applied to the board, two ICs near the PCI-E connectors get extremely hot (>75C) within a couple seconds. No other area on the motherboard is thermally active.

I have identified one part as a TI TPS54328 Synchronous Step-Down Converter, however I can't seem to identify the other part in order to get a datasheet.

Unidentified chip:
8 Pins
Logo somewhat looks like an 'M' or an 'H'
Part markings:
F44
P02
JJGI 702

Images:
Chips in question, unidentified chip is top right
[image: Chips in question, unidentified chip is top right]

Thermal Image
[image]

I appreciate any help! I'm trying to understand what this chip does so I can determine whether it is broken, or if something connected to it is causing it to draw too much current and heat up.

Thanks!

Comment: Logo is "Excelliance MOS". Probably a emf44p02. Not an answer because I can't find a datasheet for it in that package to confirm.

Comment: I think you found it! Thank you so much! I was able to find the exact part by searching EMF44P02V on Aliexpress. It's in the same QFN-8 package as well :) No luck on a datasheet. I might try removing this part and see if the board will get any further along in the bootup sequence.

Comment: Err... do you think the problem could be that your PCB looks like the Sahara desert? You could have a short caused by dust anywhere. How about cleaning up the board with compressed air before anything else?